# How many times does Dumbledore use the Pensieve in the films?

Tags: harry-potter, movie, albus-dumbledore, pensieve

I wondered how many times the Pensieve is used by Albus Dumbledore in the films?

Answer (score 2):

### I counted him using it four times.

The first time the Pensieve appears it's *Harry* who's using it, to view Barty Crouch Junior's trial. Dumbledore doesn't use it then.

The first time Dumbledore uses it himself is in *Goblet of Fire*. He's seen putting memories into it whilst having a discussion with Moody, Snape and McGonagall.

The Pensieve does make an appearance in *Order of the Phoenix* but it's Harry which uses it here during an Occlumency lesson, not Dumbledore.

The second time Dumbledore uses it is in *Half-Blood Prince* to view the memory of his first meeting with Riddle.

The third time he uses it is in the same film to view the doctored memory of Riddle's meeting with Slughorn.

The fourth time he uses it is again in *Half-Blood Prince*, this time to view the genuine Slughorn memory.

Comment: @ the dark lord spying on dumblydore? Unbelievable